# Java Object superclass

Tags: java

I have a weird Java question:

As we know:

1. All Java classes extend `java.lang.Object`
2. All Java classes cannot extend itself

Then, `java.lang.Object` must extend `java.lang.Object`, which is itself, therefore, it should be impossible. How is Object implemented in Java?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Object` is an exception to the first rule, and has no superclass. From [JLS3 8.1.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.4):

> The extends clause must not appear in the definition of the class Object, because it is the primordial class and has no direct superclass.

You can also try it out with reflection:

```
Object.class.getSuperclass(); // returns null
```

Comment: And from the introduction of chapter 8 of the JLS: "Each class except Object is an extension of (that is, a subclass of) a single existing class (§8.1.4) and may implement interfaces (§8.1.5)".

Comment: The interfaces and primitive classes don't extend Object.class either.  Map.class, boolean.class, int.class, void.class etc.

Comment: @Peter: those aren't classes.

Comment: @Michael: those _ARE_ `Class<?>` objects. `Class<?> klazz = boolean.class;` and do whatever you want with `klazz`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: A `Class<?>` object is not a class. It's metadata about a *type*.

Comment: @Michael. klass instanceof Class == true.  primitive classes are a particular type of Class and int.class.getSuperclass() == null. Interfaces are stored in a class file and represented by a Class object and an instance of Class not an instance of Interface.  Perhaps Java makes the distiction, however its not as clear at the JVM level IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off thinking of this as:

1. All java classes must implement the interface implied by the methods in java.lang.Object.

   The concrete class java.lang.Object provides default implementations of these functions.

   All other java classes are derived from the object java.lang.Object and may choose to use or override the default implementations of the methods.

The two main points are: all the classes must implement the implied interface and the Java language spec gives you (forces upon you?) default implementations for these methods for free.

Answer (score 0):

Object does not extend itself. It is the superclass for all other objects in the Java language. Think of it as being the level-0 (or root) class of all the objects in the Java API tree - including any objects you create as well.

I also just want to point out that your question is proven impossible by rule #2 that you posted. Your logic used to justify your question only takes #1 into account and is therefore extremely flawed.