# Classes that don't inherit Object class

Tags: java, object

Are there any classes that don't inherit Object as SuperClass or maybe have become Obsolete/deprecated?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [Java Object superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706069/java-object-superclass), `java.lang.Object` does not extend `Object`.

Other than that, all classes, i.e.

```
class ClassName {
    //some stuff
}
```

implicitly extend Object class, if they don't extend any other super-class.

Interfaces, on the other hand, do not extend Object, as Interface, by definition, can not extend Class.
Also, Interfaces can not contain callable methods, nor can objects be instantiated from them. When interfaces are finally implemented, the implementing class will necessarily extend Object (and, no, `Object` doesn't implement or extend any other entity/class/interface).

Comment: This was very important point, atleast for me `All classes implicitly extend Object if no other superclass is given.`

Comment: Yes, since Object is the parent of all classes, then every class must extend Object (directly xor indirectly). The indirect case is explicit, for example `class ClassName extends SuperClass`. The direct case, however, is optionally implicit - meaning you don't have to write `class ClassName extends Object`, Java will just infer that for you. But if you think of all classes having an `extends`, then it is easier to see how all classes derive from Object.

Answer (score 6):

According to [java.lang.Object javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has
>   Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the
>   methods of this class.

So, all objects in Java extends it directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

All Java classes inherit `java.lang.Object` (directly - by default, or via parents). If some class or method become deprecated with some platform release, it is always reflected in appropriate JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any classes that don't inherit Object as SuperClass

There is exactly one of those, and it is `java.lang.Object` itself. Also all interfaces.

> or maybe have become Obsolete/deprecated?

There are plenty of those. See the Javadoc.

Comment: By Obsolete/deprecated I meant, had there been any class ever in history of java that never inherited Object Class, maybe it has become obsolete in due time. I guess all the answers above suggest NO.