# Does every java class inherit from Object class implicitly

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Classes that don’t inherit Object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684305/classes-that-dont-inherit-object-class)

I am wondering if each class in Java is inherited from Object implicitly. I am reading a book which said no, I got quite confused.

Comment: Exactly which book are you reading, and who was the idiot who wrote it?

Comment: Could you give a reference or exact quote? Maybe the book was talking about direct inheritance? Every class is either a direct or indirect subclass of Object.

Comment: @JackManey idiots do not generally write programming books, they tend to stick to management. My guess is the OP misread or misunderstood something.

Comment: Why downvotes to this question? Indeed it is very sensible question. Please care to explain.

Comment: Here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684305/classes-that-dont-inherit-object-class

Comment: So this does not violate the principle of inheriting from only one class?

Answer (score 7):

That book is lying. Take a look at [*any*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class from the Java API and you'll notice the very first parent class is, in fact, [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

BTW : what is that book anyway?

** **Edit** **

Let's clarify one thing first :

**Q:**  **Does every java class inherit from Object class implicitly?**

**A:** If you consider that the class `Object` cannot have a superclass "[because it is the primordial class and has no direct superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)", then **no**, therefore your book was right.

However, if you consider that "[the class `Object` is a superclass of all other classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)", and is excluded from the question (as a class cannot inherit itself), then by definition **yes**.

---

From my understanding of the language and it's specifications, is that "[all class and array types inherit the methods of class `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)" should be taken litteral. Meaning that *every* object created possess the methods defined in the class `Object`. For this reason, and since the class `Object` has no superclass (because there is no superclass from the specification!), and also since all class inherits those methods (the methods are available in *any* object created by the JVM), then if a class does not explicitly extends `Object` (because it's not the class `Object`), it does so implicitly by itself or from a superclass by the virtual machine.

Comment: Well there is no implicit `extends Object` if there is an explicit `extends Foo`. Of course the root class *must* be `Object`.

Comment: Or, if there is an explicit `extends Foo`, then there's an implicit `extends Object`.

Comment: Somewhere in the hierarchy there is of course. But the implicit `extends Object` goes away as soon there is a explicit `extends`. It's just about the wording.

Comment: A class can only extend one class, and only has one direct superclass. There is no implicit "extends Object" for a class that extends a different class. Of course, if you follow the superclass chain you always end at Object.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, of course that is the implicit inheritance :) Because as a class extends some other class, that other class also comes with the `Object` public interface.

Comment: @YanickRochon If class X is declared to extend class Y, then X inherits Y's implementation of e.g. toString, if X does not override it. If class X extends Z which extends Y, and Z overrides toString then X inherits Z's toString, not Y's. Direct and indirect subclassing are different, and I don't yet know which the book was talking about.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, fair enough. However my point is that, whatever a class extends any other class *(explicit inheritance)* or not *(implicit inheritance)*, at some point the `Object` methods will be available, thus why you can cast *any* object (even `Object` itself) as `Object obj = (Object) anyOtherObject;`

Comment: @YanickRochon I prefer "direct" and "indirect", rather than "explicit" or "implicit". A class that has no "extends" clause implicitly but directly extends Object.

Comment: Does this not violate the principle of OOP if apart from inheriting from Object I inherit from some self made class as well? In Java we can only extend one class however we can implement many.

Comment: @Skynet, not really, since inheritance is like a chain; `SomeClass -> Object`, then if you extend another self made class : `SomeClass -> SelfMadeClass -> Object`. Therefore, `SomeClass` implicitly inherits from `Object` (as Patricia Shanahan stated), and does not violate single class inheritance.

Comment: So if I extend from a class by myself (explicitly) - this class will not extend from object? I am not talking of Class A (Which extends from object) and Class B which extends from A. But I am talking of Class B which extends from Object (implicitly) and extends from Class A explicitly? Or maybe I am wrong - just clearing concepts. I think when we declare extends explicitly  it no more forces the object to be extended? So there exists no class A which extends from object and CLass B at the same time?

Comment: @Skynet If you want a more literal explanation, take a look at the JavaDoc for [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and see the very first parent is `java.lang.Object`. (The class `Object` is in the `java.lang` package because it is a language-specific class.). And, looking at the source for [AbstractCollection](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.java.html), you can see that it does not explicitly extends `Object` (btw: an interface cannot inherit from a class), but `ArrayList` possess all methods from `Object`. :)

Comment: Thanks Yanick, you have been a great help, Ill take a look there :)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

```
public class Object
```

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has
>   Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the
>   methods of this class.

Answer (score 1):

The book can be correct in one case. The `Object` class doesn't extends `Object`. But remember every other does.
See documentation.
[Class Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: If you take this argument literally, then you could argue that not all node of a tree is under the root node because the root node has no root node... makes no sense.

Comment: Good point. Object is the only class that has no superclass. I'm still not convinced that the book is wrong rather than misunderstood. It is impossible to tell which without an actual quote.

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: I think you have misunderstood my answer. I don't say that "all nodes of a tree are not under the root". I only say that "root node of a tree is not under the root node".

Comment: @prageeth, alright, I agree with you then. The `Object` class would be an exception, but since this class is practically useless as is (or perhaps only when using some unsafe locking method...), you have to consider it a "special" case :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see... Class inherit from Object:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

```
public final class Class<T>
    extends Object
    implements Serializable, GenericDeclaration, Type, AnnotatedElement
```

throw this book to Trash!!