# Java explanation

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, reflection

Of course, I used to believe, that all Java classes inherits from Object class:
[Classes that don't inherit Object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684305/classes-that-dont-inherit-object-class) . Only Object class is exception.

But the following text: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html says that "Of course, this only works for reference types which all inherit from Object".

Does this implies that firs statement is false.

Also there is a possibility to compile other languages code into Java bytecode. Does those inherit from Object?

Comment: I guess Object does not "inherit" from Object so maybe it would be more precise if we said all classes are 'instanceof' Object which includes Object.

Comment: Yes, it might be true, because reflection applies to Object as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understood that sentence wrong. In German we use a comma to prevent such missunderstandings. In English it is optional. I guess it should be "this only works for reference types, which all inherit from Object". Or otherwise said "this only works for reference types because they all inherit from Object".

Answer (score 3):

Key part of that quote is `"this only works for reference types"`, value types are excluded (int, long, etc.) As for your second question, yes other langueses can compile into java bytecode; e.g. scala

Comment: And as I can guess Scala classes inherits from Object too.