# what components do exist in any java class?

Tags: java, class

I'm a beginner, and there was a question in the quiz that says: "what are the things that you can find in any java "class"?" 
My answer was: constructors and methods.
But I didn't really know the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684305/classes-that-dont-inherit-object-class Google is your friend

Comment: `public class MyClass {}` is a valid class definition. After this, you have all the methods inherited from `Object` and a default constructor.

Comment: Also it can be a `private` class, but he´s right thats all. Class could be completely empty but it´s an `Object`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classes that don't inherit Object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684305/classes-that-dont-inherit-object-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is everything that every Java class has:

1. A class name.
2. A class access ... implicitly *package private*, if you don't specify one.
3. A package ... implicitly the default package, if you don't specify one.
4. A superclass ... implicitly `java.lang.Object`, if you don't specify one.
5. A body which may be empty.
6. A constructor ... implicitly a default no-args constructor, if you don't specify one.